# Terra Mystica - Taking a bonus card with coins on the final turn as an Alchemist

Tags: terra-mystica

The Alchemists' special ability is to turn gold into victory points at any point in the game.

So on the last turn, when passing, could I take a bonus card with coins built up on it, and immediately trade them in for victory points? I assume you gain the stacked-up coins as soon as you gain the card.

But my friend thinks it is illegal to make the trade to victory points, as my game is technically over. Who is right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do this.

When you pass at the end of the last round, you do not take a bonus card. From the rules about passing:

> ...immediately return your Bonus card and take one of the three available ones. ... *(Exception: Do not take any Bonus cards in the last round of the game - round 6.)* ...

So you don't even *get* a bonus card in the last round.

Any coins you do have at the end of the game, however you got them, can be converted into VP. Everyone can do this at 3 coins per VP, and the Alchemists can do it at 2 coins per VP. But you can't get those coins in the way you mention in the question anyway.

Comment: @Stormdamage This is misleading. The question asks about coins built-up on a card, not a card that provides coins with income. You DO get those coins as soon as you take the card. Further, the question implies that Stormdamage and his friend think that Alchemists cannot use their ability after the game is over. This is also incorrect; all players can trade their resources down to coins and then VP as part of final scoring, Alchemists get a VP per 2 coins instead of per 3 coins.

Comment: That being said, it is still true that you do not take a new bonus card at the end of round 6.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood the question, saw "with coins" in the title and skimmed over "built up" in the body. Removed the unnecessary discussion about income not mattering.

Answer (score 4):

You are both incorrect.

You do not take a new Bonus tile when you  pass during round 6, so you cannot get any additional coins this way.

> ...immediately return your Bonus card and take one of the three available ones. ... *(Exception: Do not take any Bonus cards in the last round of the game - round 6.) ...*

However, it sounds like your friend is under the impression that Alchemists cannot use their ability at the end of the game, and this is incorrect. From the end-game scoring rules:

> Finally, get Victory points for left-over resources: get 1 Victory
>   point per 3 Coins. (All other resources may be converted to Coins
>   for this purpose, see “Conversions” on page 13.)
>   (**The Alchemists get 1 Victory point per 2 Coins.**)

So you do not have to convert all your coins to VP using your ability before you pass. It is done automatically when counting up final scores. This means that *if* you did take a new bonus tile when you pass during round 6 (though you don't), then you would get the points for the coins that are on it.

Note that coins that have built-up on a bonus tile due to not being chosen are separate from coins that a bonus tile provides as income. You get the coins that are built-up on it when you take the bonus tile:

> If there were Coins on
>   the newly taken Bonus card, put them on your Faction
>   board

But you only get the coins that it gives for income at the start of the following round, during the income phase.